# All the "year in moderation" Meta questions link to a search on the main (not Meta) sites for previous "year in moderation" questions

Tags: bug, status-completed, per-site-meta, statistics

The title covers the question - the "2020: a year in moderation" posts that [JNat ♦](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/208518/jnat) has kindly posted all follow a template which appears to be of the form:

> `As we say goodbye to the old year and welcome the new one, we have [a tradition of sharing moderation stats for the past 12 months](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q="year+in+moderation"+is%3Aquestion).`

Note that the URL results in a search query that searches the main site, not the Meta site, for questions called "year in moderation".

Looking at the first ten [Stack Exchange sites ordered by traffic](https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list#traffic):

It is still broken:

- [on Meta Super User](https://meta.superuser.com/q/14391/581487)
- [on Ask Ubuntu Meta](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/19487/529101)
- [on English Language & Usage Meta](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/14899/109567)
- [on Meta Server Fault](https://meta.serverfault.com/q/9707/348292)
- [on Mathematics Meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33035/154015)
- [on Arqade Meta](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15532/144595)
- [on Ask Different Meta](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3982/179143)
- [on English Language Learners](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5388/32732)

It is fixed:

- [on Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/404558/1364007) - by [me](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1364007/wai-ha-lee) ([history](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/404558/revisions))
- [on Unix & Linux Meta](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5729/165218) - by [Jeff Schaller ♦](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/users/117549/jeff-schaller) ([history](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/5729/revisions))

I'm assuming this was done at least in part with some kind of tool as 169 of these questions were posted between 18:09:21 and 20:07:53 (an average of 42 seconds per post) - so haven't checked any of the other 159 questions.

Is it possible to automatically fix the links? I would suggest edits to fix them but (a) I don't have 2000 reputation points on most sites so I get "Suggested edits are not allowed on non-tag-wiki posts on meta sites.", and (b) there are many of them and I'm assuming it would be possible to not have to do it manually.

Comment: It was fixed also on MathOverflow Meta: https://meta.mathoverflow.net/posts/4839/revisions https://meta.mathoverflow.net/revisions/4839/2 (And maybe other sites outside the top 10 - this one I happened to know.)

Comment: @Martin I also did on few

Comment: We have a script that posts them and it also has the ability to mass edit them. I've poked JNat to let him know that we need to see if we can fix this. :) Thanks for bringing it up!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As Catija noted [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/359839/all-the-year-in-moderation-meta-questions-link-to-a-search-on-the-main-not-me#comment1200934_359839), these were all posted using a script that can also be used to mass edit them — I ran it this morning, and just checked that all posts should now be pointing to the right place.

Comment: Did you also update the script to ensure that the correct links will be generated when posting next year? :-)

Comment: As long as the right variable is used next time the links should be fine, yup ^_^